# Casting in C# with interfaces to be able to use all object functionality

Tags: c#, interface

I'm having a bit of an issue casting my objects in C# to be able to use the additional object methods besides the ones declared in the interface. Below is a simple example of what I am speaking about.

```
public interface IShape
{
    void Print();
}

public class Square : IShape
{
    #region IShape Members

    public void Print()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Square Print Called"); 
    }   

    #endregion

    public void PrintMore()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Square Print More Called"); 
    }        
}
```

Why when this code below is called am I not able to access PrintMore()?

```
IShape s = (Square)shape;
s.PrintMore() // This is not available. only Print() is.
```

Any help and explanation would be helpful?

Comment: Because your object is an "IShape" and not a "Square". It's a cast "issue". It's totally normal :)

Comment: Your endregion is in the wrong place. That's a bit confusing.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I don't think it is. There is only one method on the interface and that is inside the region. The non-interface method is outside of it...

Comment: @Chris check the edit history. It was, at the time of the comment.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Ah, my apologies. I usually try to be good about that but obviously missed it this time. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `s` variable is still of type `IShape`. Just because you happen to have used a cast when assigning to it doesn't change the type as far as the compiler's concerned. You'd need:

```
Square s = (Square) shape;
s.PrintMore();
```

Of course, this will only work if `shape` really *is* a `Square` (assuming there aren't custom conversions going on).

I would advise you to think carefully before going down this route though. Usually a cast like this indicates that you're breaking abstraction somewhat - if you only know about `shape` as an `IShape`, you *should* (usually) be able to do what you need just with the members of `IShape`. If that's not the case, you can:

- Make `IShape` more powerful (give it more members)
- Change your code to accept a `Square` instead of an `IShape`
- Cast if absolutely necessary

Comment: Thanks for the points. I'm attempting to get to the point that I fully understand the correct approach to take and the reasoning behind it. Sometimes the solution is great, but if you never understand why, it does not help.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are trying to access `PrintMore()` off of an `IShape` reference, `IShape` references only see the `Print()` method they declare.

So the cast you have `(Square) shape` is doing nothing because it is immediately storing it into an `IShape` reference.  You need the reference itself to be `Square` by either casting and storing it in a `Square` reference, or by casting before the invoke:

```
Square s = (Square) shape;
s.PrintMore();
```

Or

```
IShape s = shape;
((Square)s).PrintMore();
```

Or, if you aren't sure if it's a `Square` or not, use an `as` cast:

```
Square s = shape as Square;

// will cast if it is a Square, otherwise, returns null 
// this doesn't work for value types (int, struct, etc) 
if (s != null)
{
    s.PrintMore();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the line `IShape s = (Square)shape;` you are telling the compiler that s is an IShape so only methods on IShape are available.

If you user:

```
Square s = (Square)shape;
s.PrintMore()
```

Then that should do what you want.

The key point here is that when you declare a variable you tell the compiler what it is and it doesn't then matter what object you put into that.

Answer (score 2):

```
IShape s = (Square)shape; 
s.PrintMore();
```

With this code `s` is still an `IShape`, not a `Square`. A variable keeps the type you have defined at his declaration, whatever you try to fill in it.

To work the code should be :

```
Square s = (Square)shape; 
s.PrintMore();
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question -- why?

Comment: @JoelEtherton : added some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are unable to access the `PrintMore` method is because you're reassigning the type-casted shape, back to a variable defined as `IShape`. To be able to use methods on the `Square` class you need to store it in a variable of type `Square` for example:

```
Square s = (Square)shape;
s.PrintMore();
```

or alternatively:

```
((Square) shape).PrintMore();
```

Although it might be worth taking a good look at your code, type-casts such as these are usually a good warning sign that perhaps it is not ideal. Perhaps `IShape` should have the `PrintMore` method, or perhaps you should only be accepting `Square` objects at this point? At the very least I'd suggest making sure that the `shape` is actually of type `Square` before doing this type cast.

For example:

```
Square s = shape as Square;

if (s != null)
    s.PrintMore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you try `s.PrintMore()` "s" is of type IShape, so it only knows about the interface functions. You'd need to do something like

```
Square s = (Square)shape;  
s.PrintMore();
```

or

```
((Square)shape).PrintMore(); // assuming you're positive its a Square type
```

Think of the interface like a wrapper over your object that only exposes only the functions defined in the interface. They're still there, you just can't access them without a cast to the appropriate object.